# SLDS Grind: how to prevent the inner spacing form being bigger than the outer spacing?

Tags: slds, slds-grid

For my taste the visual appearance of https://archive-2_0_3.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/grid has a flaw.

In all the examples the elements have just a "normal" kind of padding, which results in having the total gap between elements to be about double the size of the left and rightmost outer paddings. This looks very unclean to my eyes...

Is there a simple way to get just an equal distance of spacing OR no spacing at left-most and right-most but any spacing between? If I remember right, good old bootstrap did that with a trick using negative margins on a wrapper-div is there something like this in SLDS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this, from the Grid blueprint page:

> You can remove this by adding a slds-grid_pull-padded-[size] class to the slds-grid container. The [size] portion of this class should be the name of the spacing utility size you've applied to the outermost columns.

https://lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#Column-Gutters